# Meeting invite sent to users also getting sent to group user is in

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2003, outlook, outlook-2003

When someone sends a meeting invite addressed only to me it also gets sent to a group I am in and everyone in that group gets the meeting invite also.  I get 2 invites in my inbox, The first one is to my email and then I get one addressed to the group that I am in. Other people in the group do not have this issue.

How do I remove that group from getting invites addressed only to me?

Server 2003, Exchange 2003, Outlook 2007

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/235765/meeting-invite-sent-to-users-also-getting-sent-to-group-user-is-in) (originally on SO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was causing it.  I had the group set up as a delegate in Outlook under Tools—Options—Delegates.  That caused it to send the meeting invite to the group.  After I removed it stopped sending the invite to the group.